# Solving the integral $\int_{0}^{t} ds \sqrt{\frac{s}{t-s}} \operatorname{erfc}\left(\frac{a}{\sqrt{s}}\right)$

Tags: calculus, probability, integration, definite-integrals, error-function

I want to solve the following integral
$$
\int_{0}^{t} ds \sqrt{\frac{s}{t-s}} \operatorname{erfc}\left(\frac{a}{\sqrt{s}}\right)
$$
with $a\in\mathbb{R}$ and $t\in\mathbb{R}^+$. I have tried some substitutions and the most promising are

1. $u=\sqrt{t-s} \ \left(du=-\frac{1}{2\sqrt{t-s}} \  ds\right)$ so that the integral becomes
   \begin{align}
   \int_{0}^{t} ds \sqrt{\frac{s}{t-s}} \operatorname{erfc}\left(\frac{a}{\sqrt{s}}\right)
   &=-2\int_{\sqrt{t}}^{0}du\ \sqrt{s}\operatorname{erfc}\left(\frac{a}{\sqrt{s}}\right)\\
   &=\color{orange}{2\int^{\sqrt{t}}_{0}du\ \sqrt{t-u^2}\operatorname{erfc}\left(\frac{a}{\sqrt{t-u^2}}\right).}
   \end{align}
2. $v=\frac{1}{\sqrt{s}} \ \left(dv = -\frac{1}{2s^{3/2}} \ \ \ ds \right)$ which yields
   \begin{align}
   \int_{0}^{t} ds \sqrt{\frac{s}{t-s}} \operatorname{erfc}\left(\frac{a}{\sqrt{s}}\right)
   &=2\int_{\tfrac{1}{\sqrt{t}}}^{\infty} dv \ v^{3/2} \frac{1}{v\sqrt{t-\tfrac{1}{v^2}}} \ \operatorname{erfc}\left(av\right)\\
   &=\color{orange}{2\int_{\tfrac{1}{\sqrt{t}}}^{\infty} dv \ \frac{v^{3/2}}{\sqrt{v^2t-1}}  \ \operatorname{erfc}\left(av\right)}
   \end{align}

Furthermore, I have looked at the table of integrals [[1](https://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/jres/73B/jresv73Bn1p1_A1b.pdf**)], [[2](https://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/jres/75B/jresv75Bn3-4p149_A1b.pdf)] and [[3](http://keithbriggs.info/documents/erf-integrals.pdf)]. However, so far, no luck. Is there someone who knows a way forward?

Comment: Use parts + definition of exponetial integral

Comment: Many thank for the suggestion! <3 I will explore it

Comment: There is an error in the substitution from $u$ to $v$: it should be $\mathrm{d} v = \frac{u}{(t-u^2)^{3/2}} \mathrm{d} u$. Also, $(t-u^2)^2 = v^{-4}$. With these changes the final integral becomes quite a bit more complicated.

Comment: Wow indeed! Sorry for this embarrassing mistakes. I will edit the question.

Comment: No worries, thanks for editing! However, there is still a small mistake: now it should be $\mathrm{d} v = - \frac{1}{2 s^{3/2}} \mathrm{d} s$.

Comment: Hahaha luckily it is just a typo! Thanks @ComplexYetTrivial!

Comment: Have a look at my edit and let me know. Cheers :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $s=\frac {a^2}{x^2}$ to make
$$\int_{0}^{t}\sqrt{\frac{s}{t-s}} \operatorname{erfc}\left(\frac{a}{\sqrt{s}}\right)\,ds=2a^3\int_{\frac{a}{\sqrt{t}}}^\infty\frac{\text{erfc}(x)}{x^3 \sqrt{t x^2-a^2}}\,dx$$

I do not think that the antiderivative can be computed but the definite integral is

$$I=\int_{0}^{t}\sqrt{\frac{s}{t-s}} \operatorname{erfc}\left(\frac{a}{\sqrt{s}}\right)\,ds=t \,\,G_{2,3}^{3,0}\left(\frac{a^2}{t}|
\begin{array}{c}
 1,2 \\
 0,\frac{1}{2},\frac{3}{2}
\end{array}
\right)$$

where appears the Meijer G function. This has been checked numerically.

Let $y=\frac t{a^2}$ and then
$$\frac I{a^2}=y \,\,G_{2,3}^{3,0}\left(\frac{1}{y}|
\begin{array}{c}
 1,2 \\
 0,\frac{1}{2},\frac{3}{2}
\end{array}
\right)$$

To allow comparison with numerical integration, I give you below a few values
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 y & \frac I{a^2} \\
 0 & 0.00000 \\
 1 & 0.16389 \\
 2 & 0.74897 \\
 3 & 1.55103 \\
 4 & 2.47510 \\
 5 & 3.47872 \\
 6 & 4.53912 \\
 7 & 5.64249 \\
 8 & 6.77981 \\
 9 & 7.94477 \\
 10 & 9.13278
\end{array}
\right)$$

**Edit**

I forgot to mention that this is valid only for $a>0$. I did not find any solution for $a<0$.

What is interesting is the expansion of $\frac I{a^2}$ for large values of $y$. It write
$$\frac I{a^2}=\frac \pi 2 y-\frac{4 }{\sqrt{\pi }}\sqrt{y}\Bigg[1+ \sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^n \frac {\alpha_n+\beta_n \big[\log(4y)-\gamma\big]} {\delta_n\,y^n}\Bigg]$$ The first $\alpha_n$ make the sequence
$$\{5,9,20,193,921,1075,9839,265715,\cdots\}$$ the first $\beta_n$
$$\{3,10,21,180,770,819,6930,175032,\cdots\}$$  the first $\delta_n$
$$\{18,400,4704,248832,7434240,62300160,4644864000,1145485393920,\cdots\}$$ None of them in $OEIS$.

Using this truncated expansion for $y=1$ leads to an absolute error of $7.13\times 10^{-8}$ and, for $y=10$ to an absolute error of $5.33\times 10^{-15}$.

Comment: Thanks @Claude_Leibovici! How did you think of Meijer G function when trying to find you answer? I will doubly check it and let you know my findings :D.

Comment: @drandran12. I have spending a long time on this problem. I had a long answer showing the problems until appeared ComplexYetTrivial's comment appeared. So, I gave up. I was suspecting some hypergeometric function. This was confirmed by a CAS. I must confess that I was not expecting so complex as Meijer G.

Comment: Yeah, again sorry for that embarrassing mistake :/. I very much appreciate the answer! Wich CAS did you use?

Comment: I have found a different expression in terms of only two hypergeometric functions. I will typo it out in the nearest future. However, I will accept your answer as the final answer.

Comment: @drandran12. I am waiting for it. Cheers & thanks   :-)

Answer (score 4):

If you substitute $av=x$ you are left with the problem of evaluating an integral of the form
$$
\int_z^{ + \infty } {\frac{\operatorname{erfc}x}{{x^2 }}dx},\quad z>0 .
$$
Using integration by parts once yields
$$
\int_z^{ + \infty } {\frac{{\operatorname{erfc}x}}{{x^2 }}dx}  = \frac{{\operatorname{erfc}z}}{z} - \frac{2}{{\sqrt \pi  }}\int_z^{ + \infty } {\frac{1}{x}e^{ - x^2 } dx}  = \frac{{\operatorname{erfc}z}}{z} - \frac{1}{{\sqrt \pi  }}E_1 (z^2 ),
$$
where $E_1$ is the exponential integral.

Comment: Thank you very much @asgeige and @Gary!!!

Comment: I made a huge mistake in my substitution. Sorry @Gary! I will edit the question. However, as @ComplexYetTrivial stated the integral is complicated by the substitution.

Answer (score 2):

Let us start from the second substitution in the question, i.e.
\begin{align}
 f(a)
 =2\int_{\tfrac{1}{\sqrt{t}}}^{\infty} dv \ \frac{v^{3/2}}{\sqrt{v^2t-1}}  \ \operatorname{erfc}\left(av\right)
\end{align}
and take the partial derivative w.r.t. the variable a
\begin{align}
 \partial_a f(a)
  & =2\int_{\tfrac{1}{\sqrt{t}}}^{\infty} dv \ \frac{v^{3/2}}{\sqrt{v^2t-1}}  \ \left[ -\frac{2 v e^{-a^2 v^2}}{\sqrt{\pi }} \right] \\
  & =-\frac{4}{\sqrt{\pi}}\int_{\tfrac{1}{\sqrt{t}}}^{\infty} dv \ \frac{v^{5/2}}{\sqrt{v^2t-1}}e^{-a^2 v^2}
\end{align}
Mathematica solves the remaining integral for all $t > 0$
\begin{align}
  & \partial_a f(a)                   \\
  & =-\frac{4}{\sqrt{\pi}}\left[
  \frac{\frac{\ \Gamma\left[\frac{5}{4}\right] \, _1F_1\left[\frac{1}{2},-\frac{1}{4},-\frac{a^{2}}{t}\right]}{\left(\frac{a^{2}}{t}\right)^{5 / 4}}+\frac{\sqrt{\pi} \ \Gamma\left[-\frac{5}{4}\right] \, _1F_1\left[\frac{7}{4}, \frac{9}{4},-\frac{a^{2}}{t}\right]}{\ \Gamma\left[-\frac{3}{4}\right]}}{2 t^{7 / 4}}
 \right]                         \\
  & =-\frac{4}{\sqrt{\pi}}\left[
  \frac{\sqrt{\pi } \ \Gamma \left(-\frac{5}{4}\right) \, _1F_1\left(\frac{7}{4};\frac{9}{4};-\frac{a^2}{t}\right)}{2 t^{7/4} \ \Gamma \left(-\frac{3}{4}\right)}+\frac{\sqrt[4]{t} \ \Gamma \left(\frac{5}{4}\right) \left(\frac{a^2}{t}\right)^{3/4} \, _1F_1\left(\frac{1}{2};-\frac{1}{4};-\frac{a^2}{t}\right)}{2 a^4}
 \right]                         \\
  & =-\frac{4}{\sqrt{\pi}}\left[
  \frac{\sqrt{\pi } }{2} t^{-7/4}\frac{\ \Gamma \left(-\frac{5}{4}\right) }{  \ \Gamma \left(-\frac{3}{4}\right)}  \, _1F_1\left(\frac{7}{4};\frac{9}{4};-\frac{a^2}{t}\right)+\frac{1}{2 \sqrt{t} a^{5/2}} \ \Gamma \left(\frac{5}{4}\right) \, _1F_1\left(\frac{1}{2};-\frac{1}{4};-\frac{a^2}{t}\right)
  \right]
\end{align}
We know that
\begin{align}
 f(\infty)-f(a) = \int_a^\infty \partial_a f(a)
\end{align}
Because $f(\infty=0)$ one can write
\begin{align}
 f(a)=- \int_{a}^{\infty} \partial_a f(a)
\end{align}
From now we must set a constraint. If somebody can solve for a general $a \in \mathbb{R}$, please let me now!

If we assume that $a>0$, Mathematica solves the integral which gives
\begin{align}
  & f(a)                         \\
  & = \frac{4}{\sqrt{\pi}}\left[
  \frac{\frac{10 \ t^{5/4} \ \ \ \Gamma \left(\frac{1}{4}\right) \ _2F_2 \ \left(-\frac{3}{4},\frac{1}{2};-\frac{1}{4},\frac{1}{4};-\frac{a^2}{t}\right)}{a^{3/2}} \ \ \ +\sqrt{2} \left(\frac{128 a \ \Gamma \left(\frac{7}{4}\right)^2 \ \ _2F_2 \ \left(\frac{1}{2},\frac{7}{4};\frac{3}{2},\frac{9}{4};-\frac{a^2}{t}\right)}{\sqrt{\pi }} \ \ +5 \sqrt{t} \ \Gamma \left(\frac{1}{4}\right)^2\right)}{120 t^{7/4}}
  \right]
\end{align}
Simplifying and putting on a multiline yield
\begin{multline}
 f(a) = \frac{4}{\sqrt{\pi}}\frac{\ \Gamma \left(\frac{1}{4}\right)^2}{12 \sqrt{2} t^{5/4}}+\frac{4}{\sqrt{\pi}}\frac{16 \sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi }} a \ \Gamma \left(\frac{7}{4}\right)^2 \ _2F_2\left(\frac{1}{2},\frac{7}{4};\frac{3}{2},\frac{9}{4};-\frac{a^2}{t}\right)}{15 t^{7/4}}\\
 +\frac{4}{\sqrt{\pi}}\frac{\ \Gamma \left(\frac{1}{4}\right) \ _2F_2\left(-\frac{3}{4},\frac{1}{2};-\frac{1}{4},\frac{1}{4};-\frac{a^2}{t}\right)}{12 a^{3/2} \sqrt{t}}
\end{multline}
Doing this once more gives
\begin{multline}
 f(a) = \frac{1}{3\sqrt{2\pi}t^{5/4}}\ \Gamma \left(\frac{1}{4}\right)^2+\frac{ 64 \sqrt{2}\ a }{\sqrt{\pi}15 t^{7/4}} \ \Gamma \left(\frac{7}{4}\right)^2 \ _2F_2\left(\frac{1}{2},\frac{7}{4};\frac{3}{2},\frac{9}{4};-\frac{a^2}{t}\right)\\
 +\frac{1}{ 3\sqrt{\pi}a^{3/2} \sqrt{t}}\ \Gamma \left(\frac{1}{4}\right) \ _2F_2\left(-\frac{3}{4},\frac{1}{2};-\frac{1}{4},\frac{1}{4};-\frac{a^2}{t}\right)
\end{multline}
$\color{red}{\text{Again, we have assumed that $a>0$ would be nice also find the expression for }a \in \mathbb{R}.}$

Comment: @Claude_Leibovici any idea to perform the integral for a<0?

Comment: We can do exactly the same with the initial integral but this leads to the integration wrt $a$ of $$-2 \sqrt{t} \,\,G_{1,2}^{2,0}\left(\frac{a^2}{t}|
\begin{array}{c}
 \frac{3}{2} \\
 0,1
\end{array}
\right)$$ Just looping in circles